# React's "npm run build" command gives error while running in "Virtual environment"

Tags: reactjs, django, virtualenv

I'm trying to use react for front-end in Django project in a virtual environment.

Steps I followed,

1. Create a virtual environment
2. Create a Django project in the same folder
3. Create a react app in the same folder
4. cd to react app
5. Run "npm run build"

I'm getting an error here saying, "'Export' is not recognized as the internal or external command"

Log,

```
'''
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.15
3 info using node@v14.18.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~prebuild: frontend@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: frontend@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\code\PortfolioOct21\frontend\node_modules\.bin;D:\code\PortfolioOct21\venv\Scripts;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.11.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python39\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Chromedriver;C:\Program Files\Python39\Scripts;C:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\himan\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\bin;;C:\Users\himan\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: CWD: D:\code\PortfolioOct21\frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'export NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf ./build && webpack --env.production --optimize-minimize'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@0.1.0 build: `export NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf ./build && webpack --env.production --optimize-minimize`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:293:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd D:\code\PortfolioOct21\frontend
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.18.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.15
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error frontend@0.1.0 build: `export NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf ./build && webpack --env.production --optimize-minimize`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
'''
```

Comment: `export` is not valid on `windows`, you should use `set`.

Comment: Tagging OS information must be helpful. It seems like windows (`C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\...`) yeah but as i said it will be more reachable question.

Comment: From the steps I mentioned, in which step exactly the modification is needed?
I'm a beginner.
Where should I exactly edit?
`export NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf ./build && webpack --env.production --optimize-minimize`
**I didn't manually write the above line of code.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

`set NODE_ENV=production && ...`

instead of

`export NODE_ENV=production && ...`

`set` is required on windows side.

---

In your `scripts`  section at `package.json` file,

find and replace below line

`export NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf ./build && webpack --env.production --optimize-minimize`

with this

`set NODE_ENV=production && rm -rf ./build && webpack --env.production --optimize-minimize`

Comment: Where exactly should I write this code?
I'm a beginner. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It replaces the previous error with the new error saying, " rm is not recognized as the internal or external command". I tried to replace `rm` with `rd /s /q dist` but the new error popped saying " Invalid switch: build".
Everything works perfectly fine if I'm outside the virtual environment.
Is there anything that I need to install in virtual env ? @Batuhan